# How do I convert an object of class tbl_mysql into tbl_df using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the following code to download a mysql table and assigning it to the object `nycflights`

```
library(dplyr)    
my_db <- src_mysql(dbname = "dplyr",
                       host = "dplyr.csrrinzqubik.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
                       port = 3306,
                       user = "dplyr",
                       password = "dplyr")
    nycflights <- tbl(my_db, "dplyr")
```

Then, I would like transform this object in a dataframe of class tbl_df before doing computations using dplyr. The reason is that there are a few functions that do not work with a table of class tbl_mysql. For example

```
> nycflights %>%
 sample_n(1)
Error: Don't know how to sample from objects of class tbl_mysql
```

The reason is that records in a mysql db don't have an intrinsic order, thus cannot be random sampled.

Back to my questions, I tried 3 different approaches:

First:

```
> tbl_df(nycflights)
Error: data is not a data frame
```

Second:

```
> as_data_frame(nycflights)
Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists
```

Third, which is simply too slow and it crashes after a while:

```
tbl_dt(nycflights)
```

**UPDATE**

The question I asked is probably of very low practical use. There are very few circumstances in which the user would need to `collect()` the whole dataset. Also, to fetch a random sample on a `tbl_mysql` object, I could use this code:

```
nycflights %>% 
  mutate(x=rand()) %>% 
  collapse() %>% 
  filter(x<=.0001) %>% 
  select(-x) %>% 
  collect()
```

Keep in mind that `rand()` is an actual mysql function. This point was confusing to me, because I was using `random()` as suggested in this [r studio seminar](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/working-with-big-data-in-r/)

Comment: I thought the question was well phrased but apparently is not. Could someone suggest how to improve it?

Comment: What is your error message when you run sample_n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collect()` for this purpose. From the help:

> `collect` also forces computation, but will bring data back into an R `data.frame` (stored in a `tbl_df`).

It takes a little while to run, but I assume this is normal given the size of the data set:

```
system.time(nycflights_local <- collect(nycflights))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   1.177   0.404  17.839 
class(nycflights_local)
## [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

If you prefer to have a `tbl_dt`, you can convert easily:

```
nycflights_dt <- tbl_dt(collect(nycflights))
class(nycflights_dt)
## [1] "tbl_dt"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"
```

As opposed to the OP, I can also use `tbl_df()` directly on `nycflights`, however the resulting `tbl_df` object is trimmed to the first 100'000 rows:

```
nycflights_dt2 <- tbl_dt(nycflights)
## Warning message:
## Only first 100,000 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all.
```

With `nycflights_local`, you can use `sample_n()`:

```
sample_n(nycflights_local, 5) %>% select(id:day)
## Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
## 
##       id  year month   day
##    (int) (int) (int) (int)
## 1  89847  2013    12     8
## 2  18669  2013     1    22
## 3  70178  2013    11    16
## 4 219012  2013     5    28
## 5 144250  2013     3     9
```

Comment: Thanks, I was considering `collect()` too but I wonder if there is another way to do the same. My concern is, why `collect()` doesn't let you choose between `tbl_dt` and `tbl_df`? My guess is that `collect()` is supposed to be used to print out the result of the query, rather than pulling the data locally. I'll wait a bit and see if somebody else comes up with another solution before accepting yours.

Comment: You can easily convert `tbl_df` to `tbl_dt`. I don't think that `collect()` is for printing, since you can print the `tbl_mysql` object directly. As the help states, `collect()` is there to "bring data back into an R data.frame".

Comment: True. Also, I wonder if the logic behind is that under no circumstances you might need to pull a `tbl_mysql` as a `tbl_dt` cause any msyql table is gonna look like  "a list of variables of the same number of rows".

Comment: `tbl_df` is a wrapper for a data frame, so it definitely is  "a list of variables of the same number of rows". I think the reason that `collect()` returns a `tbl_df` is that  data frames (or `tbl_df`) are the standard data type of`dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do with with sample_n. It works for me.
the db"MySQL" is a 20 mil obs. database, and wanna sample 1 mil data.
took me awhile to make it work.

```
con <- src_mysql(dbname="MySQL")

db.smpl <- con %>% tbl("MySQL") %>%   
        tbl_df() %>% 
        sample_n(1e6, replace = F) %>% data.table()
```

BTW, I can't find tbl_dt now.